# How could I render a variable string value from html into flask?

Tags: html, flask

```
{% for k,v in titlef.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ k }}</td>
        <td>{{ v }}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/templates/{{k}}"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If I want to render k value in the flask then how could I do this?
k contains a products name and that will be a string of more than 1 word
I have tried like this but it didn't work:

```
@app.route('/templates/<k>',methods=["POST"])
def reg2(k):
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flask`'s `url_for` function, just pass your parameter as keyword argument:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('templates', k=k)}}"></a>
```

One more thing It's better to make sure `k` doesn't contain 'space', you can use `join` filter:

```
{{ k|join("-") }}
```

Comment: What will be the syntax for python's code? Because if I try this then it is giving an error

Comment: Your view function is fine. Just in html code do changes. What error can you add here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VtUJfxniCr4XUK0k9yN3sOD8jE719BsA   I have uploaded the pictures here, please have a look

Comment: `k` contains `/` character if you check, so It change the url. Btw It will be hard to put a long string in the url. I recommend you to use something short.